# How to write a custom function that has the same behavior of inbuilt Array Join in Node.js

Tags: javascript

```js
function arr(a) {
  let sum = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sum += a[i] + "-";
  }
  console.log(sum);
}

arr(["Hello", "World", "!"]);
```

It's printing "-" after "!" as well

Comment: You should check whether `i === a.length - 1` to decide whether to add `"-"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should probably return your joined string from the function and *then* log the result.
2. Maybe also pass in a delimeter argument so you don't just have to use "-"; you can use anything. And that will mirror the `join` method a lot better.
3. Most importantly: check that the current index is less than the length of the array (-1). If it is add the delimeter. If it the equal to `length - 1` don't add it.

```js
function join(arr, delimeter) {
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i < arr.length - 1) {
      str += arr[i] + delimeter;
    } else {
      str += arr[i];
    }
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(join(['Hello', 'World', '!'], '-'));
console.log(join(['We', 'Have', 'Popcorn', '!'], ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to determine rendering last dash

```js
function arr(a){
  let sum= "";
  for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    i === a.length-1 ? sum+=a[i] : sum+= a[i]+"-";
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
arr(["Hello","World","!"]);
```

Comment: You should document your code because the OP probably doesn't know what a conditional operator is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to add one condition for the last item. For example

```
function arr(a){
  let sum= "";
  for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      sum+= a[i] + ((i<a.length-1) ? "-" : "");
  }
  return sum
}
const result = arr(["Hello","World","!"]);

console.log(result)
```

Or it's neater with array reduce

```
const join = (arr, separator) => {
  return arr.reduce((prev, current)=> prev + separator +  current)
}

const rs =join(["Hello", "World", "!"], "-")
console.log(rs)
```

Same result

```
"Hello-World-!"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this as follow

```js
function arr(a,glue='') {
  let sum = "";
  let i=0;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
    sum += a[i] + glue;
  }
  sum+=a[i];
 return sum;
}

console.log(arr(["Hello", "World", "!"],"-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function arr(a) {
    let sum= "";
    for (let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if (i==a.length-1) {
            sum = sum + a[i];
        } else {
            sum = sum + a[i] + "-";
        }
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
arr(["Hello","World","!"]);
```